# Successfully compiled on Mac, but linking error on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, macos, ubuntu

I tried to use [Jellyfish](https://github.com/gmarcais/Jellyfish/), a bioinformatics software. Everything went well in [make] and [make install]. The executable bin file also works. What I want is to compile my own code against the Jellyfish include files and the shared libraries.

I tried to compile the following simple code, which is very simple, with only one declaration of hash_counter.

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <jellyfish/mer_dna.hpp>
#include <jellyfish/hash_counter.hpp>

typedef jellyfish::cooperative::hash_counter<jellyfish::mer_dna>  mer_hash_type;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  jellyfish::mer_dna::k(25); // Set length of mers (k=25)
  const uint64_t hash_size    = 10000000; // Initial size of hash.
  const uint32_t num_reprobes = 126;
  const uint32_t num_threads  = 16; // Number of concurrent threads
  const uint32_t counter_len  = 7;  // Minimum length of counting field
  const bool     canonical    = true; // Use canonical representation

  // create the hash
  mer_hash_type mer_hash(hash_size, jellyfish::mer_dna::k()*2, counter_len, num_threads, num_reprobes);

  return 0;
}
```

This code can be successfully compiled on Mac using the command below

```
$g++ -std=c++11 -I/home/jellyfish_lib/include/jellyfish-2.2.5  -L/home/jellyfish_lib/lib -lpthread -ljellyfish-2.0 test.c -o test
```

but failed when compiled on Ubuntu (with g++ 4.9), with the following error,

```
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `jellyfish::quadratic_reprobes'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::random_bits()':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish11random_bitsEv[_ZN9jellyfish11random_bitsEv]+0xa): undefined reference to `jellyfish::random_bits(int)'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `allocators::mmap::~mmap()':
test.c:(.text._ZN10allocators4mmapD2Ev[_ZN10allocators4mmapD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `allocators::mmap::free()'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix::RectangularBinaryMatrix(unsigned int, unsigned int)':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish23RectangularBinaryMatrixC2Ejj[_ZN9jellyfish23RectangularBinaryMatrixC5Ejj]+0x1d): undefined reference to `jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix::alloc(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix::RectangularBinaryMatrix(jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix const&)':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish23RectangularBinaryMatrixC2ERKS0_[_ZN9jellyfish23RectangularBinaryMatrixC5ERKS0_]+0x23): undefined reference to `jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix::alloc(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix::randomize_pseudo_inverse()':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish23RectangularBinaryMatrix24randomize_pseudo_inverseEv[_ZN9jellyfish23RectangularBinaryMatrix24randomize_pseudo_inverseEv]+0x24): undefined reference to `jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix::randomize_pseudo_inverse(unsigned long (*)())'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::locks::pthread::barrier::barrier(unsigned int)':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish5locks7pthread7barrierC2Ej[_ZN9jellyfish5locks7pthread7barrierC5Ej]+0x1f): undefined reference to `pthread_barrier_init'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::locks::pthread::barrier::~barrier()':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish5locks7pthread7barrierD2Ev[_ZN9jellyfish5locks7pthread7barrierD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `pthread_barrier_destroy'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::large_hash::array_base<jellyfish::mer_dna_ns::mer_base_static<unsigned long, 0>, unsigned long, atomic::gcc, jellyfish::large_hash::array<jellyfish::mer_dna_ns::mer_base_static<unsigned long, 0>, unsigned long, atomic::gcc, allocators::mmap> >::array_base(unsigned long, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short, jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix, unsigned long const*)':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish10large_hash10array_baseINS_10mer_dna_ns15mer_base_staticImLi0EEEmN6atomic3gccENS0_5arrayIS4_mS6_N10allocators4mmapEEEEC2EmtttNS_23RectangularBinaryMatrixEPKm[_ZN9jellyfish10large_hash10array_baseINS_10mer_dna_ns15mer_base_staticImLi0EEEmN6atomic3gccENS0_5arrayIS4_mS6_N10allocators4mmapEEEEC5EmtttNS_23RectangularBinaryMatrixEPKm]+0x269): undefined reference to `jellyfish::RectangularBinaryMatrix::pseudo_inverse() const'
/tmp/ccKzjmVq.o: In function `jellyfish::large_hash::array<jellyfish::mer_dna_ns::mer_base_static<unsigned long, 0>, unsigned long, atomic::gcc, allocators::mmap>::alloc_data(unsigned long)':
test.c:(.text._ZN9jellyfish10large_hash5arrayINS_10mer_dna_ns15mer_base_staticImLi0EEEmN6atomic3gccEN10allocators4mmapEE10alloc_dataEm[_ZN9jellyfish10large_hash5arrayINS_10mer_dna_ns15mer_base_staticImLi0EEEmN6atomic3gccEN10allocators4mmapEE10alloc_dataEm]+0x1f): undefined reference to `allocators::mmap::realloc(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems something went wrong during linking. Does anyone have experience about this?

Comment: I don't think you have compiled jellyfish software header and libraries on ubuntu, that is why it is unable to find those functions, or the compiler is unable to find correct headers properly, try to give proper path to header files.

Comment: @AkashSinha Thanks. Actually I've compiled header and lib, and specified the path by -I and -L parameters. But no idea why it didn't work.